# Compare JPA Entity and DTO

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, lombok

I need a standard approach to compare a JPA Entity to it's DTOs and determine if they represent the same business object.  I can think of three approaches, a custom method on each DTO, an interface with a static method or a comparator.

Building on the answer from *João Dias*, approach 4 - Inheritance.

Pros/Cons

- Approach 1 - Bad all the way around
- Approach 2 - Uses interface to favor composition over inheritance but requires semantics using custom method name (`businessKeysMatch()`)
- Approach 3 - Does not require the source code to be modified
- Approach 4 - Simplifies semantics as it uses standard `equals()` but requires "boilerplate `equals()/hashcode()`

Any other pros/cons of the approaches or suggestions on other approaches?

*In the end, I chose to use approach 2 (Interface).  The Inheritance approach showed promise but one of the classes being a JPA Entity made the mapping more complex than I wanted.*

Thanks for reading and thinking about my question!

**Background**

Entity

- a database key
- a business key that is unique enforced at ORM and database that determines equality (`equals()`/`hashcode()`)
- public attributes (name, address, age, etc)
- non-public / confidential attributes (password, refresh token, SSN, etc)

  ```
    @Data
    @EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
    @Entity
    @Table(uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "businessKey1", "businessKey2" }) })
    class UserEntity {
        @Id
        Long id;
        @NotNull
        @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
        Long businessKey1;
        @NotNull
        @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
        Long businessKey2;
        String name;
        Integer age;
        String password;
        String refreshToken;
        String SSN;
    }
  ```

DTO (full)

- business key that determines equality (`equals()`/`hashcode()`)
- public attributes (name, address, age, etc)

  ```
    @Data
    @EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
    class UserDto {
        @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
        @NotNull
        Long businessKey1;
        @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
        @NotNull
        Long businessKey2;
        String name;
        String address;
        Integer age;
    }
  ```

DTO (limited)

- business key that determines equality (`equals()`/`hashcode()`)
- selected public attributes (name)

  ```
    @Data
    @EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
    class UserNameDto {
        @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
        @NotNull
        Long businessKey1;
        @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
        @NotNull
        Long businessKey2;
        String name;
    }
  ```

**Approach 1** - Custom method added to each User*Dto

```
    boolean businessKeysMatch(UserEntity entity) {
        if((this.getBusinessKey1() == entity.getBusinessKey1()) && (this.getBusinessKey2() == entity.getBusinessKey2()))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

**Approach 2** - Add static method to common interface

```
    interface UserKeys {
        Long getBusinessKey1();
        Long getBusinessKey2();
        static boolean businessKeysMatch(UserKeys o1, UserKeys o2) {
            if((o1.getBusinessKey1() == o2.getBusinessKey1()) && (o1.getBusinessKey2() == o2.getBusinessKey2()))
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    }

    class UserEntity implements UserKeys {
        // no other changes
    }

    class UserDto implements UserKeys {
        // no other changes
    }

    class UserEntity implements UserKeys {
        // no other changes
    }
```

**Approach 3** - Comparator

```
    interface UserBusinessKey {
        Long getBusinessKey1();
        Long getBusinessKey2();
    }

    class UserDto implements UserCompare {
        // no other changes
    }

    class UserEntity implements UserCompare {
        // no other changes
    }

    class UserCompare implements Comparator<UserBusinessKey> {
        public int compare(UserBusinessKey o1, UserBusinessKey o2) {
            int key1Compare = o1.getBusinessKey1().compareTo(o2.getBusinessKey1());

            if (key1Compare == 0) 
                return o1.getBusinessKey2().compareTo(o2.getBusinessKey2());
            return key1Compare;
        }
    }
```

**Approach 4** - Inheritance with equals/hashcode of base class only

```
    @SuperBuilder
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Data
    abstract class UserBase {
        @NotNull
        Long businessKey1;
        @NotNull
        Long businessKey2;
        // lombok generates a standard equals() / hashcode() pair
    }

    @SuperBuilder
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ToString
    @Entity
    @Table(uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "businessKey1", "businessKey2" }) })
    class UserEntity extends UserBase {
        @Id
        Long id;
        String name;
        Integer age;
        String password;
        String refreshToken;
        String SSN;
        
        // handcoded equals/hashcode that only call super
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return super.equals(obj);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return super.hashCode();
        }
    }

    @SuperBuilder
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ToString
    class UserDto extends UserBase {
        String name;
        String address;
        Integer age;
        
        // handcoded equals/hashcode that only call super
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return super.equals(obj);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return super.hashCode();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple `User*Dto` I would create an abstract `AbstractUserDto` that would be then extended by all you concrete User DTOs. There you could place the method that you show in your Approach 1 (so that you don't duplicate the same code over and over again):

```java
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public abstract class AbstractUserDto {
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @NotNull
    Long businessKey1;
    
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @NotNull
    Long businessKey2;
    
    String name;

    public final boolean businessKeysMatch() {
        return (this.getBusinessKey1() == entity.getBusinessKey1()) && (this.getBusinessKey2() == entity.getBusinessKey2());
    }
}
```